# get the name of the nav-item on which it was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have  a `navbar` designed in `Bootstrap`,I want to get the name of the `nav-item` on which it was clicked. I can set it to active currently but unable to retrieve the name of the nav-item. How to achieve this?

I am aware of the `nodeName` in jQuery which get the name of the node but I want to get the content inside of that node apparently.

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse animated fadeInLeft" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getItem = $(this);
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + getItem + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
        $('.navbar-toggler').click();
    });
});
```

my Current output is `[object][object]` butI want to get `Home` if that is currently active or `Pricing` if that is currently active.

PS:**Using Bootstrap 4**

Comment: You need to specify what you want to get from the this: $(this).text()

Comment: LOL,I knew this was silly. Thanks,move this comment to the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what you want to get from the this, use `$(this).text()` to get innerText, or `$(this).html()` to get innerHtml.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` is the `li` object, you want to use `$(this).text()` like this

```js
   $('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var getItem = $(this).text();
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + getItem + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
        $('.navbar-toggler').click();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse animated fadeInLeft" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

  <div class="navbar-brand"></div>
```